# How can I set Idea collapse too long string?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, folding

Look at Eclipse:

[image]

and in Idea:

[image]

So, how can I make Idea collapse multiline String like Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it seems there are no folding options for string literals.

You could try using [custom folding tags](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/code-folding.html#using_folding_comments), but this could will require extra comments for every string:

[image]

To check all existing folding options go to `Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

CMD + . on Strings to fold them

[image: CMD + . on Strings to fold them]